# Collect jbpm error that occur in a workflow

Tags: java, jbpm

How can errors(ex. if a scriptTask fails) be collected from jbpm and send to an external system (ex. kafka)?

Answer (score 0):

In jBPM 7.1 new approach to error handling was introduced.
You can find more details in this [blog post](http://mswiderski.blogspot.com/2017/06/execution-error-how-to-deal-with.html)

I have not tested this: but you can try to implement your own version of ExcecutionErrorStorage, which will be responsible for storing messages in Kafka.

You can take a look at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.error.DefaultExecutionErrorStorage for reference, in there DB is used as Error Storage.